# making input fields styled when they contain values

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, styles

How do I make the mandatory fields in my input form have a red border when the page is loaded and they are empty, and how to set them back-to-normal styling when they have data inside?

I have this code:

Page:

```html
<form method="post" action="xxx.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" value="multipart/form-data" onload="borderColour()">
   <div>
      <label for="firstName">First Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First name &hellip;">
   </div>
   <div>
      <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last name &hellip;">
   </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```js
// Border colour for input web forms
function borderColour() {

    var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
    var firstNameId = document.getElementById('firstName');
    var lastNameId = document.getElementById('lastName');

    if (firstName == '') {
        firstNameId.addClass("form-required");
    } else {
        firstNameId.removeClass("form-required");
    }
    if (lastName == '') {
        lastNameId.addClass("form-required");
    } else {
        lastNameId.removeClass("form-required");
    }
}
```

CSS:

```css
.form-required {border: 2px solid red !important;}
```

Comment: onload runs immediately after the component is loaded, shouldn't you run this function when the user submits the form?

Comment: No, because the result needs to be dynamic while the form is being filled in - border switches from red to grey when the field has a value. This is long before the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using CSS rather than JavaScript:

```
input,
input:placeholder-shown {
  /* default <input> styles */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  /* has a value entered */
  border-color: gray;
}
```

References:

- [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).
- [`:placeholder-shown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown).

Comment: By doing that, the input will be marked as wrong before the user even tries to input anything into it.

Comment: This works and works well.  I'm now trying to extend this to work the same way with lists like this where the value "Select" is basically the placeholder for the list - .list-required
  {border: 1px solid grey;}
.list-required option[value="Select"]
  {border: 1px solid red;}

Answer (score 0):

I cant add a comment so, I see that your css selector missing a dot to define a class. If that is not the problem let me know.

#### EDIT:

Ok the problem is you are using `AddClass()` as a function but it is a `jQuery` function. You need to use `.classList.add("form-required")` method instead.
And same with the `removeClass` method. Instead you should use `.classList.remove("form-required")`

And dont forget to call your function after the function definition.
Like this:

```
borderColour();
```

#### Final Advise

But you need an `event listener` instead of calling your function `once on page load`.
So you need to add this function to maybe a keypress event on the inputs.

#### Sample Code

**HTML**

```
<form id="theForm" method="post" action="xxx.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" value="multipart/form-data" onload="borderColour()">

<div>
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First name &hellip;">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last name &hellip;">
</div>

</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-required {border: 2px solid red !important;}
```

**Javascript(Pure Vanilla)**

```
// Border colour for input web forms
function borderColour() {

// You could use below comment to select all inputs but you will probably need to select a textarea too. So selection is a next step. 
//var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var firstNameSelector = document.getElementById('firstName');
var value = firstNameSelector.value;
  console.log(firstNameSelector.value);
  if(value == '') {
       firstNameSelector.classList.add("form-required");
     }
  else {
   firstNameSelector.classList.remove("form-required");
       }

}
//Adding an event listener to the form element. If you click outside the form you will get the class toggle if the input is empty it will get the red border an so on...
document.getElementById("theForm").addEventListener("focusout", borderColour);
```

You can add the event listener to all the input elements but to do that you will need a loop(maybe a foreach) like in the other answers.

Comment: The dot is there, just a bad copy/paste from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet

```js
// Border colour for input web forms
function borderColour(e) {
  if(e.target.value == '') {
     e.target.setAttribute("class", "form-required");
  } else {
     e.target.removeAttribute("class");
  }
}

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(function(el){
  el.onpropertychange = borderColour;
  el.oninput = borderColour;
});
```

```css
.form-required {border: 2px solid red !important;}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="xxx.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" value="multipart/form-data" onload="borderColour()">

<div>
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First name &hellip;">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last name &hellip;">
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should consider moving the event listening to the script

You can use `querySelectorAll()` here to get a node list of all the inputs instead of selecting each one individually

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

inputs.forEach(function (input, index) {
  input.addEventListener("input", () => toggleClass(index));
});
```

Then you should create a function to toggle the class using `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()` instead of `addClass()`

```js
const toggleClass = (index) => {
  if (inputs[index].value === "") {
    inputs[index].classList.add("form-required");
  } else {
    inputs[index].classList.remove("form-required");
  }
};
```